# Uploading photo with caption or status to Facebook on iPhone app

Tags: iphone, facebook

I managed to implement Facebook connect on my iPhone app and allow the user to upload a status update via the app. I now want to include a feature to allow uploading of photos together with a caption or status update. Does anyone know the relevant code for this?

I think I'm supposed to use the photos.upload API in FB but am not too sure how. The Facebook documentation all seems very generic with no specific code for iPhone development. Any assistance or sample code with be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This following snippet is taken from the [facebook-ios-sdk](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/). Assuming your class already has a facebook object, this method will upload a photo from a URL (change as needed):

```
-(IBAction) uploadPhoto: (id)sender {
  NSString *path = @"http://www.facebook.com/images/devsite/iphone_connect_btn.jpg";
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
  UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

  NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  img, @"picture",
                                  nil];
  [facebook requestWithMethodName: @"photos.upload"
                         andParams: params
                     andHttpMethod: @"POST"
                       andDelegate: self];
  [img release];
}
```

In order to send a caption with the photo you must add the "message" parameter key followed by the caption text. Changing `params` like below should achieve this:

```
NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                img, @"picture", 
                @"my photo's caption text here.", @"message"
                                nil];
```

Comment: I am having difficulties in using the sample code from facebook.  I constantly get an error code The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 101.)" UserInfo=0x4b46da0 {request_args=(
        {
        key = method;
        value = "photos.upload";
    },
        {
        key = sdk;
        value = ios;
    },
        {
        key = "sdk_version";
        value = 2;
    },
        {
        key = format;
        value = json;
    }
), error_msg=Invalid API key, error_code=101}
Anyone can shed some light?

Comment: My first thought is to make sure that when the login happens, that @"publish_stream" is one of the requested permissions allowing you to publish to the user. Unfortunately the github example only has:     _permissions = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"read_stream", @"offline_access",nil] retain]; Add @"publish_stream" and it should work.

Comment: Thanks very much for sharing the code. It really helped me a lot... the only problem I am facing is that my caption ain't being uploaded. I am using exactly the same code u mentioned but nothing getting uploaded in caption field.

Comment: The `@"message"` text shows up for me under "In this photo:". There is a `@"caption"` parameter that might be what you want, but I don't know where that text goes. I never saw it anywhere associated with the image.

Comment: How can I get facebook object?

Comment: I am afraid that I have not worked with the Facebook object in years. That said, it looks like there are changes on the very near horizon via Facebook. Perhaps someone can address this?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload photo by using iOS Facebook SDK as follows:

```
    FBSDKSharePhoto *photo=[[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc]init];
    photo.image=slideImage;

    FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
    content.photos = @[photo];

    [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self];

This works only if you configure iPhone Facebook settings.
```