# How to upload a photo with a link on Facebook from iPhone?

Tags: iphone, facebook

I follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390483/uploading-photo-with-caption-or-status-to-facebook-on-iphone-app) answer to post a photo on Facebook. How can I add a link to the photo? i.e., when visitors click on the uploaded photo, it open the pre-defined link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simple, just use the href key in the media attachment dictionary.

```
{"media": [
    { 
        "type": "image", 
        "src": "http://icanhascheezburger.files.wordpress.com/2009/03/funny-pictures-kitten-finished-his-milk-and-wants-a-cookie.jpg", 
        "href": "http://icanhascheezburger.com/2009/03/30/funny-pictures-awlll-gone-cookie-now/"
    }, 
    {
        "type": "image", 
        "src": "http://photos.icanhascheezburger.com/completestore/2009/1/18/128768048603560273.jpg", 
        "href": "http://ihasahotdog.com/upcoming/?pid=20869"
    }]
}
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments