# iphone integrate facebook

Tags: iphone, facebook

i want to post any photo on to the facebook wall .so through iphone i want to develop such application please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uploading photo with caption or status to Facebook on iPhone app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390483/uploading-photo-with-caption-or-status-to-facebook-on-iphone-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use graph API for post image on facebook.

see this link:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 2):

Grab the latest [Facebook iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk), there you should find all of the posting examples to get you started. You will need to register an app on Facebook and get an Application Secret code to include in your app to test properly.