# How can I share a picture with Facebook SDK iOs

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios5, sharing

I'm developing a iOs 5 app and I've implemented Facebook SDK for iOs. I would like to share a picture so that's my code (isn't working):

```
if (buttonIndex==3) {


    if (facebook == nil) 
    {
        // Setup Facebook connection
        [self setUpFacebookConnection];
    }else {
        [self fbDidLogin];
    }          
}   

 }
- (void)setUpFacebookConnection
{
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"245697495524266" andDelegate:self];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
    && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) 
{
    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}

if (![facebook isSessionValid])
{
    NSArray* permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"offline_access", @"publish_stream", @"publish_actions", @"photo_upload", nil];

    [facebook authorize:permissions];
}
 }

 - (void)fbDidLogin{ 

 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
 [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
 [defaults synchronize];


 bannerview2.hidden=YES;

 if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
 else
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

// retrieve the current graphics context
 CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// render view into context
[self.view.layer renderInContext:context];

// create image from context
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// save image to photo album
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                               self,
                               nil,
                               @"image.png"); 
bannerview2.hidden=NO;


NSMutableString *message = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Resultado final %@: %d vs. %@: %d. Mi jugador hizo %d puntos y cometió %d faltas.",intnomlocal, puntsl, intnomvisitant, puntsv, puntsjugadorint, faltesjugadorint];




 NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:image,     @"picture", message,@"message", nil];

  [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];    

}
```

So it all works unless the part of sharing the picture in -(void) fbDidLogin. How can I fix it?

Comment: what exactly happens in fbDidLogin and where is the "wrong" behavior?

Comment: @LordT In fbDidLogin tha app must make a snapshot and upload it to Facebook, but the last part doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the necessary permissions. As per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/ you need the permission publish_stream. However, even with that permission, i'm not 100% sure that you're allowed to post to me/photos. Try posting to the feed first!

[edit] turns out I was wrong. To upload an UIImage, you need both the user_photos, publish_stream and upload_photos permission and post to me/photos - you can't post to me/feed with an image to upload.

The newer facebook api explorer, directly from fb, is a bit better. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

You can check the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) under "Publishing" for what and where you can publish. Note that you can only upload photos to existing albums, for which you need the album-ID.

You should implement the [FBRequestDelegate](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/FBRequestDelegate/) protocol in your class to see what's failing and how.

[edit 2] check this post: [other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390483/uploading-photo-with-caption-or-status-to-facebook-on-iphone-app) - it seems you really need the publish_stream permission as well. Try it again, if you can't get around it, I'll setup a test environment.

Comment: I added publish_stream. So if i can't post on me/photos where can i post to?

Comment: to what are you posting? me/feed? or me/photos?

Comment: I'm post in to me/feed. When it says PROFILE_ID what have I got to put: me or my username of Facebook?

Comment: me should be equivalent to your PROFILE_ID, so you can use that. WHat is the response you're getting when you implement FBRequestDelegate?

Comment: I got that Failed with error: The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)

Comment: please check my newest edit. i think you have to use me/photots with photo_upload, user_photos permission. me/stream only works with URL or graph objects

Comment: Now with photo_upload, user_photos and me/photos I'm receiving Failed with error: The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 101.)

Comment: When it says FBAccessToken do i have to change it for the number that i get on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?

Comment: Which permissions did you use? i think you need the publish_stream permission as well for some undocumented reason..

Answer (score 0):

try to add the access token in params dic

```
 NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:image,  @"picture",message,@"caption",[facebook accesstoken],@"access_token",nil];
```

Comment: use me/photos instead of me/feed .. in case you want it as feed you need to set an url to the image not send it as object.